# Connected with limited access (drivers?)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, network-adapter

My PC with Windows Vista had some wireless problems 3 years ago, so I bought a wireless adapter, which worked fine.
But a few days ago, it suddenly didn't connect anymore; the network manager says it is "connected with limited access".
So I brought a new wireless adapter (TL-WN823N), but the error does still occur.
When I look at the problem it says there are driver or hardware issues, but it is the same on both adapters except the name.

Thanks in advance!

Note: It does work on other PC's.

Comment: Try Windows Diagnostics. What does it reports?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia It can't report because the internal network card doesn't work anymore, that's why I bought the adapter

Comment: Your question is a little too vague for anyone to help you much. Is it recognized and working if you boot to another OS from CD, like Ubuntu? Also, have you tried any diagnostics on the motherboard? Try the card in a different slot? Does a wired connection work? Are you positive the wireless network you are trying to connect is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be a problem with your usb drivers. Try reinstalling your usb drivers and then reinstall your wireless NIC's drivers as well. If that doesn't work, i would recommend you to take your PC to a local IT shop for inspection.